# Is $(window).scrollTop() the correct statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I'm trying to build a function like this one:

```
var t =$('#top');
var q1=$('#fe1');
var q2=$('#fe2');
var q3=$('#fe3');
var q4=$('#fe4');
var q5=$('#fe5');
var win = $(window);
var doc=$(document);
var wins = win.scrollTop();
var docs = doc.scrollTop();


function next (){
    if (wins == docs) {
        q1.ScrollTo();
    }
    else if (wins == q1.scrollTop()) {
        q2.ScrollTo();
    }
    else if (wins == q2.scrollTop()) {
            q3.ScrollTo();
    }
    else if (wins == q3.scrollTop()) {
        q4.ScrollTo();
    }
    else if (wins == q4.scrollTop()) {
        q5.ScrollTo();
    }
}
```

I want to go scrolling to the next section. To do so, the code checks in which section I am so it knows which section to scroll to. But I think `$(window).scrollTop()` is not what I am looking for.

I want a statement that returns the distance between the top of the page and the top of what I am displaying. Maybe i have to do a more complex operation. Do you know how can i get this?

Thanks.

Comment: why are you "*sorry*"?

Comment: I think you want to `<` or `>` instead of `==`.

Comment: why do you say so? i didn't say sorry

Comment: $(window).scrollTop() is exactly what you need.

Comment: post it as an answer;)

Comment: Are you using the scrollTo plugin ?? where is the ScrollTo() defined ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a link go to the next anchor on the page without knowing anchor name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225621/how-can-i-make-a-link-go-to-the-next-anchor-on-the-page-without-knowing-anchor-n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is quite simple to solve even without jQuery or similar in plain JavaScript. Here it is for your example:

```
var next = (function (sections) {

    function getTop(node) {
        return node ? node.offsetTop + getTop(node.offsetParent) : 0;
    }

    return function () {
        var i, nodeTop, top = window.pageYOffset;

        for (i = 0; i < sections.length; i += 1) {
            nodeTop = getTop(document.getElementById(sections[i]));
            if (nodeTop > top) {
                window.scrollTo(window.pageXOffset, nodeTop);
                return;
            }
        }
    };
}(['top', 'fe1', 'fe2', 'fe3', 'fe4', 'fe5']));
```

The code is quite general, so you can pass any section ids you want (they just need to appear in the correct order).

We use two standard DOM properties/functions here `window.pageYOffset` and `window.scrollTo()` to get and set vertical offset of the window (`window.pageXOffset` is used to keep horizontal offset the same). To get the vertical offset of the section start I defined `getTop` function using simple recursion (jQuery uses similar code IMHO).

Resulting function `next()` is defined in a self-invoking closure to hide the implementation and helper function. To use it after this code is run, you simply call

```
next();
```

I tested this code, so I am quite confident it works :).