# Scroll to NEXT/PREV buttons with Bootstrap ScrollSpy

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I was looking through answers for creating next and prev buttons that go through anchor points on a page, but couldn't find something I need. This one might of been close to what I wanted so I decided to use it as a starting point: [How can I make a link go to the next anchor on the page without knowing anchor name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225621/how-can-i-make-a-link-go-to-the-next-anchor-on-the-page-without-knowing-anchor-n)

I created a fiddle with the concept presented in that answer and tried to make it work together with bootstrap's scrollspy (detects the current section and anchor).

I have gotten this far: http://jsfiddle.net/gukne0oL/2/

```
$('.next').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var current_anchor = $('li.active a');
    var next_anchor = current.next('li a');
    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: next_anchor.offset().top
    });
})

$('.previous').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var current_anchor = $('li.active a');
    var previous_anchor = current.prev('li a');
    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: previous_anchor.offset().top
    });
})
```

The original answer targets the `<a>` tag, but in bootstrap's scrollspy, it adds the `active` class to the `<li>` tag wrapping the `<a>` tag. So I changed it accordingly... I feel like it's close? but I can't tell...

Can anyone help? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Target active li, find the previous/next li, and drill down to the anchor.

http://jsfiddle.net/gukne0oL/9/

```
// Activate bootstrap scrollspy
$('body').scrollspy({ 
    target: '.navbar'
})

$('.next').click(function (e) {  
    var next = $('.navbar ul li.active').next().find('a').attr('href');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(next).offset().top
    }, 500);
})

$('.previous').click(function (e) {
    var prev = $('.navbar ul li.active').prev().find('a').attr('href');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(prev).offset().top
    }, 500);
})
```