# jquery+adobe muse issue - How to resolve code issue: Dynamic button navigation previous/next anchor?

Tags: jquery, html, adobe, muse, anchor-scroll

I am working on a webcomic with keyboard enabled navigation from panel to panel using anchors and jump/scroll code-based widget to inhance Adobe Muse.

I would like to make the navigation option available for mobile users with a set of dynamic buttons placed in the top level frame that trigger the action in a similar fashion as the keypress for up arrow and down arrow (currently fuctional but buggy).

My hope is a viewer can link to any anchor within a given chapter and navigate from anchor point to anchor point either forward or backwards (up page to last anchor point or down page to next anchor point) so it's key that the code not be dependant on a particular starting point, especially because the scroll jump to anchor code doesn't trigger on mobile platforms.

here is a link to an example chapter :

http://www.attilathe.com/chapter-5.html

As JSFiddle doesn't replicate the top level frame composure of content or the widget plugin behaviour I'm not sure how to replicate the code.

I also saw this unanswered stackoverflow question:
[How can I make a link go to the next anchor on the page without knowing anchor name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225621/how-can-i-make-a-link-go-to-the-next-anchor-on-the-page-without-knowing-anchor-n)

- I felt it was relevant but I need some help translating how to effectively add the code to Adobe Muse so that the code is placed correctly relative to the content and takes the master frame into consideration.

Thank you much in advance for your insight!

Edit addition per request -

below is chunk of the code I had to delete massive amounts of it to fit the limit here so I may have broken it inadvertently so please see the link source code if. The example chapter does not have the buttons placed as they did not function but includes buttons already completing other functions in the master frame layer that the intended buttons would be placed:

```
 <html class="js html" lang="en-US"><head>

  <script async="" src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">
   if(typeof Muse == "undefined") window.Muse = {}; window.Muse.assets = {"required":["jquery-1.8.3.min.js", "museutils.js", "webpro.js", "musewpslideshow.js", "jquery.museoverlay.js", "touchswipe.js", "jquery.watch.js", "jquery.scrolleffects.js", "chapter-5.css"], "outOfDate":[]};
</script>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="generator" content="2015.1.2.344">
  <title>CHAPTER 5</title>
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/site_global.css?4245379245">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/master_a-comic-nav.css?277903926">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/chapter-5.css?233531573" id="pagesheet">
  <!-- Other scripts -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
   document.documentElement.className = document.documentElement.className.replace(/\bnojs\b/g, 'js');
</script>
    <!--custom head HTML-->
  <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-54742566-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
<!--?php include_once("analyticstracking.php") ?-->
  <!--HTML Widget code-->

<style>
html, body {overflow-x: hidden !important;}   

</style>

 </head>
 <body data-whatinput="mouse">

  <div class="clearfix" id="page"><!-- column -->
   <div class="position_content" id="page_position_content">
    <div class="clearfix colelem" id="pu1714"><!-- group -->
     <div class="grpelem" id="u1714"><!-- custom html -->


</div>
     <div class="grpelem" id="u9156"><!-- custom html -->

</div>
    </div>
    <div class="colelem" id="u1920"><!-- simple frame --></div>
    <div class="PamphletWidget clearfix pinned-colelem wp-slideshow-playing" id="pamphletu6146"><!-- none box -->
     <div class="ThumbGroup clearfix grpelem" id="u6161"><!-- none box -->
      <div class="popup_anchor">
       <div class="Thumb popup_element wp-tab-active PamphletThumbSelected" id="u6162" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="u6150" aria-selected="true"><!-- simple frame --></div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="popup_anchor" id="u6149popup">
      <div class="ContainerGroup clearfix" id="u6149" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;"><!-- stack box -->
       <div class="Container clearfix grpelem wp-panel wp-panel-active" id="u6150" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="u6162" style=""><!-- group -->
        <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u6151"><!-- group -->
         <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u6153-6"><!-- content -->
          <p></p>
          <p></p>
         </div>
         <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u6152-10"><!-- content -->
          <p>USE ARROW KEYS</p>
          <p>OR</p>
          <p>PAGE UP / DOWN</p>
          <p>TO JUMP NAVIGATE</p>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="popup_anchor">
      <div class="PamphletCloseButton PamphletLightboxPart popup_element clearfix" id="u6156" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="close" style="display: block;"><!-- group -->
       <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u6157"><!-- group -->
        <div class="clip_frame grpelem" id="u6159"><!-- image -->
         <img class="block" id="u6159_img" src="images/dots-crop-u6159.png" alt="" width="38" height="35">
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u6158-4"><!-- content -->
         <p></p>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div><div class="colelem"></div>
    <div class="colelem" id="u5458"><!-- custom html --></div>
    <a class="anchor_item colelem" id="start"></a>
    <div class="clearfix pinned-colelem" id="u6501"><!-- group -->
     <a class="nonblock nontext clip_frame" id="u6502" href="menu.html" data-href="page:U2522"><!-- image --><img class="block" id="u6502_img" src="images/dots-crop-u6502.png" alt="" width="84" height="85"></a>
    </div><div class="colelem"></div>
    <a class="nonblock nontext clearfix pinned-colelem" id="u10301-4" href="menu.html" data-href="page:U2522"><!-- content --><p>MENU</p></a><div class="colelem"></div>
    <div class="PamphletWidget clearfix wp-slideshow-playing" id="pamphletu18523" style="left: -280px; top: 110.6px;"><!-- none box -->
     <div class="ThumbGroup clearfix grpelem" id="u18524"><!-- none box -->
      <div class="popup_anchor">
       <div class="Thumb popup_element wp-tab-active PamphletThumbSelected" id="u18525" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="u18533" aria-selected="true"><!-- simple frame --></div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="popup_anchor" id="u18532popup">
      <div class="ContainerGroup clearfix" id="u18532" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;"><!-- stack box -->
       <div class="Container clearfix grpelem wp-panel wp-panel-active" id="u18533" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="u18525" style="opacity: 0.992;"><!-- group -->
        <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u18534"><!-- group -->
         <!-- m_editable region-id="editable-static-tag-U18536-BP_infinity" template="chapter-5.html" data-type="html" data-ice-options="disableImageResize,link" -->
         <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u18536-4" data-muse-uid="U18536" data-muse-type="txt_frame"><!-- content -->
          <p></p>
         </div>
         <!-- /m_editable -->
         <!-- m_editable region-id="editable-static-tag-U18535-BP_infinity" template="chapter-5.html" data-type="html" data-ice-options="disableImageResize,link" -->
         <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u18535-4" data-muse-uid="U18535" data-muse-type="txt_frame"><!-- content -->
          <p>SCROLL</p>
         </div>
         <!-- /m_editable -->
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="PamphletWidget clearfix wp-slideshow-playing" id="pamphletu1864" style="left: -262px; top: 110.6px;"><!-- none box -->
     <div class="ThumbGroup clearfix grpelem" id="u1865"><!-- none box -->
      <div class="popup_anchor">
       <div class="Thumb popup_element wp-tab-active PamphletThumbSelected" id="u1866" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="u1871" aria-selected="true"><!-- simple frame --></div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="popup_anchor" id="u1869popup">
      <div class="ContainerGroup clearfix" id="u1869" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;"><!-- stack box -->
       <div class="Container clearfix grpelem wp-panel wp-panel-active" id="u1871" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="u1866" style="opacity: 0.992;"><!-- group -->
        <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u1888"><!-- group -->
         <!-- m_editable region-id="editable-static-tag-U1890-BP_infinity" template="chapter-5.html" data-type="html" data-ice-options="disableImageResize,link" -->
         <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u1890-4" data-muse-uid="U1890" data-muse-type="txt_frame"><!-- content -->
          <p></p>
         </div>
         <!-- /m_editable -->
         <!-- m_editable region-id="editable-static-tag-U1889-BP_infinity" template="chapter-5.html" data-type="html" data-ice-options="disableImageResize,link" -->
         <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u1889-4" data-muse-uid="U1889" data-muse-type="txt_frame"><!-- content -->
          <p>SCROLL</p>
         </div>
         <!-- /m_editable -->
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!-- m_editable region-id="editable-static-tag-U18513-BP_infinity" template="chapter-5.html" data-type="image" -->
    <div class="clip_frame colelem" id="u18513" data-muse-uid="U18513" data-muse-type="img_frame"><!-- image -->
     <img class="block" id="u18513_img" src="images/chapter%205.jpg" alt="" width="997" height="748" data-muse-src="images/chapter%205.jpg">
    </div>
    <a class="anchor_item colelem" id="f8"></a>
    <div class="clearfix colelem" id="u20093"><!-- column -->
     <!-- m_editable region-id="editable-static-tag-U23280-BP_infinity" template="chapter-5.html" data-type="image" data-ice-options="clickable" data-ice-editable="link" -->
     <a class="nonblock nontext clip_frame colelem" id="u23280" href="chapter-6.html#a1" data-href="anchor:U20374:U21661" data-muse-uid="U23280" data-muse-type="img_frame"><!-- image --><img class="block" id="u23280_img" src="images/chapter%206-crop-u23280.png" alt="" width="335" height="135" data-muse-src="images/chapter%206-crop-u23280.png"></a>
     <!-- /m_editable -->
     <!-- m_editable region-id="editable-static-tag-U20098-BP_infinity" template="chapter-5.html" data-type="html" data-ice-options="disableImageResize,link,clickable" data-ice-editable="link" -->
     <a class="nonblock nontext clearfix colelem ose_ei" id="u20098-6" href="chapter-6.html#a1" data-href="anchor:U20374:U21661" data-muse-uid="U20098" data-muse-type="txt_frame" style="opacity: 0;"><!-- content --><p id="u20098-2">CHAPTER 6</p><p id="u20098-4">WELCOME TO BAT COUNTRY</p></a>
     <!-- /m_editable -->
    </div>
    <!-- m_editable region-id="editable-static-tag-U20096-BP_infinity" template="chapter-5.html" data-type="image" -->
    <div class="clip_frame" id="u20096" data-muse-uid="U20096" data-muse-type="img_frame" data-mu-ie-matrix="progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=-1,M12=0,M21=0,M22=-1,SizingMethod='auto expand')" data-mu-ie-matrix-dx="0" data-mu-ie-matrix-dy="0" style="display: none;"><!-- image -->
     <img class="block" id="u20096_img" src="images/scroll_down_prompt-crop-u20096.png" alt="" width="100" height="66" data-muse-src="images/scroll_down_prompt-crop-u20096.png">
    </div>
    <!-- /m_editable -->
    <div class="verticalspacer"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- JS includes -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
   if (document.location.protocol != 'https:') document.write('\x3Cscript src="http://musecdn2.businesscatalyst.com/scripts/4.0/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript">\x3C/script>');
</script><script src="http://musecdn2.businesscatalyst.com/scripts/4.0/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   window.jQuery || document.write('\x3Cscript src="scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript">\x3C/script>');
</script>
  <script src="scripts/museutils.js?3790713428" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="scripts/whatinput.js?84559013" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="scripts/webpro.js?329496574" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="scripts/musewpslideshow.js?394033048" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="scripts/jquery.museoverlay.js?4265131668" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="scripts/touchswipe.js?497316881" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="scripts/jquery.watch.js?4244854265" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="scripts/jquery.scrolleffects.js?4219894366" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- Other scripts -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() { try {
(function(){var a={},b=function(a){if(a.match(/^rgb/))return a=a.replace(/\s+/g,"").match(/([\d\,]+)/gi)[0].split(","),(parseInt(a[0])<<16)+(parseInt(a[1])<<8)+parseInt(a[2]);if(a.match(/^\#/))return parseInt(a.substr(1),16);return 0};(function(){$('link[type="text/css"]').each(function(){var b=($(this).attr("href")||"").match(/\/?css\/([\w\-]+\.css)\?(\d+)/);b&&b[1]&&b[2]&&(a[b[1]]=b[2])})})();(function(){$("body").append('<div class="version" style="display:none; width:1px; height:1px;"></div>');
for(var c=$(".version"),d=0;d<Muse.assets.required.length;){var f=Muse.assets.required[d],g=f.match(/([\w\-\.]+)\.(\w+)$/),k=g&&g[1]?g[1]:null,g=g&&g[2]?g[2]:null;switch(g.toLowerCase()){case "css":k=k.replace(/\W/gi,"_").replace(/^([^a-z])/gi,"_$1");c.addClass(k);var g=b(c.css("color")),h=b(c.css("background-color"));g!=0||h!=0?(Muse.assets.required.splice(d,1),"undefined"!=typeof a[f]&&(g!=a[f]>>>24||h!=(a[f]&16777215))&&Muse.assets.outOfDate.push(f)):d++;c.removeClass(k);break;case "js":k.match(/^jquery-[\d\.]+/gi)&&
typeof $!="undefined"?Muse.assets.required.splice(d,1):d++;break;default:throw Error("Unsupported file type: "+g);}}c.remove();if(Muse.assets.outOfDate.length||Muse.assets.required.length)c="Some files on the server may be missing or incorrect. Clear browser cache and try again. If the problem persists please contact website author.",(d=location&&location.search&&location.search.match&&location.search.match(/muse_debug/gi))&&Muse.assets.outOfDate.length&&(c+="\nOut of date: "+Muse.assets.outOfDate.join(",")),d&&Muse.assets.required.length&&(c+="\nMissing: "+Muse.assets.required.join(",")),alert(c)})()})();
/* body */
Muse.Utils.transformMarkupToFixBrowserProblemsPreInit();/* body */
Muse.Utils.prepHyperlinks(true);/* body */
Muse.Utils.fullPage('#page');/* 100% height page */
Muse.Utils.initWidget('#pamphletu6146', ['#bp_infinity'], function(elem) { return new WebPro.Widget.ContentSlideShow(elem, {contentLayout_runtime:'stack',event:'click',deactivationEvent:'',autoPlay:true,displayInterval:1000,transitionStyle:'fading',transitionDuration:500,hideAllContentsFirst:true,shuffle:false,enableSwipe:false,resumeAutoplay:false,resumeAutoplayInterval:3000,playOnce:false,autoActivate_runtime:false}); });/* #pamphletu6146 */
Muse.Utils.initWidget('#pamphletu18523', ['#bp_infinity'], function(elem) { return new WebPro.Widget.ContentSlideShow(elem, {contentLayout_runtime:'stack',event:'click',deactivationEvent:'',autoPlay:true,displayInterval:3000,transitionStyle:'fading',transitionDuration:500,hideAllContentsFirst:true,shuffle:false,enableSwipe:false,resumeAutoplay:false,resumeAutoplayInterval:3000,playOnce:false,autoActivate_runtime:false}); });/* #pamphletu18523 */
Muse.Utils.initWidget('#pamphletu1864', ['#bp_infinity'], function(elem) { return new WebPro.Widget.ContentSlideShow(elem, {contentLayout_runtime:'stack',event:'click',deactivationEvent:'',autoPlay:true,displayInterval:3000,transitionStyle:'fading',transitionDuration:500,hideAllContentsFirst:true,shuffle:false,enableSwipe:false,resumeAutoplay:false,resumeAutoplayInterval:3000,playOnce:false,autoActivate_runtime:false}); });/* #pamphletu1864 */
$('#u18533').registerOpacityScrollEffect([{"fade":50,"opacity":100,"in":[-Infinity,-0.4]},{"opacity":100,"in":[-0.4,-0.4]},{"fade":50,"opacity":0,"in":[-0.4,Infinity]}]);/* scroll effect */
$('#pamphletu18523').registerPositionScrollEffect([{"in":[-Infinity,-0.4],"speed":[0,0]},{"in":[-0.4,Infinity],"speed":[0,-3]}]);/* scroll effect */
$('#u1871').registerOpacityScrollEffect([{"fade":50,"opacity":100,"in":[-Infinity,-0.4]},{"opacity":100,"in":[-0.4,-0.4]},{"fade":50,"opacity":0,"in":[-0.4,Infinity]}]);/* scroll effect */
$('#pamphletu1864').registerPositionScrollEffect([{"in":[-Infinity,-0.4],"speed":[0,0]},{"in":[-0.4,Infinity],"speed":[0,-3]}]);/* scroll effect */
$('#u20098-6').registerOpacityScrollEffect([{"fade":50,"opacity":0,"in":[-Infinity,117203.86]},{"opacity":100,"in":[117203.86,117203.86]},{"fade":50,"opacity":100,"in":[117203.86,Infinity]}]);/* scroll effect */
$('#u20096').registerPositionScrollEffect([{"in":[-Infinity,117245.86],"speed":[0,0.8]},{"in":[117245.86,Infinity],"speed":[0,1]}]);/* scroll effect */
Muse.Utils.showWidgetsWhenReady();/* body */
Muse.Utils.transformMarkupToFixBrowserProblems();/* body */
} catch(e) { if (e && 'function' == typeof e.notify) e.notify(); else Muse.Assert.fail('Error calling selector function:' + e); }});
</script>

  <!--HTML Widget code-->

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){var pos1=1;if(pos1===1){(function(){var delay=false;$(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll',function(event){event.preventDefault();if(delay)return;delay=true;setTimeout(function(){delay=false},800)
var wd=event.originalEvent.wheelDelta||-event.originalEvent.detail;var XZ="";var a=$("a:not([href])").not(XZ.replace(/\b(?=\w)/g,'#'));if(wd<0){for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){var t=a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;if(t>=85)break;}}else{for(var i=a.length-1;i>=0;i--){var t=a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;if(t<-85)break;}}
var time=700;var easing='easeInOutCirc';$("html, body").animate({scrollTop:$(a[i]).offset().top},time,easing);});})();}});$(window).load(function(){var pos1=1;if(pos1===2){(function(){$(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll',function(event){var XZ="";var a=$("a:not([href])").not(XZ.replace(/\b(?=\w)/g,'.'));var x=$(a[a.length-1]).offset();var m=(x.top)+10;var fo=$(window).scrollTop();fo=fo+500;var dox=$(a[0]).offset();var dom=(dox.top)+200;var dofo=$(window).scrollTop();if(dofo<dom){if(event.originalEvent.deltaY<0){event.preventDefault();return;}}
if(fo>m){if(event.originalEvent.deltaY>0){event.preventDefault();return;}}
$("body").css("opacity","0");var timing=500+550;var fnz=500+450;setTimeout(function(){$("body").css("opacity","1");},timing);var wd=event.originalEvent.wheelDelta||-event.originalEvent.detail;var XZ="";var a=$("a:not([href])").not(XZ.replace(/\b(?=\w)/g,'#'));if(wd<0){for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){var t=a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;if(t>=70)break;}}else{for(var i=a.length-1;i>=0;i--){var t=a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;if(t<-70)break;}}
setTimeout(function(){$("html, body").animate({scrollTop:$(a[i]).offset().top},0);},fnz);});})();;}});

jQuery.easing.jswing = jQuery.easing.swing;
jQuery.extend(jQuery.easing, {
    def: "easeOutQuad",
    swing: function(e, f, a, h, g) {
        return jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def](e, f, a, h, g)
    },
    easeInQuad: function(e, f, a, h, g) {
        return h * (f /= g) * f + a
    },
    easeOutQuad: function(e, f, a, h, g) {
        return -h * (f /= g) * (f - 2) + a
    },
    easeInOutQuad: function(e, f, a, h, g) {
        if ((f /= g / 2) < 1) {
            return h / 2 * f * f + a
        }
        return -h / 2 * ((--f) * (f - 2) - 1) + a
    },
    easeInCirc: function(e, f, a, h, g) {
        return -h * (Math.sqrt(1 - (f /= g) * f) - 1) + a
    },
    easeOutCirc: function(e, f, a, h, g) {
        return h * Math.sqrt(1 - (f = f / g - 1) * f) + a
    },
    easeInOutCirc: function(e, f, a, h, g) {
        if ((f /= g / 2) < 1) {
            return -h / 2 * (Math.sqrt(1 - f * f) - 1) + a
        }
        return h / 2 * (Math.sqrt(1 - (f -= 2) * f) + 1) + a
    },
});
</script>



<script type="text/javascript">
document.onmousewheel = function(){  (); } 
if(document.addEventListener){ 
    document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll',  , false);
}

function  (e){
    if(!e){ e = window.event; }
    if(e.preventDefault) { e.preventDefault(); } 
    e.returnValue = false; 
}

</script>




<script language="JavaScript">


var message="Right-click is disabled";


function clickIE4(){
if (event.button==2){
alert(message);
return false;
}
}

function clickNS4(e){
if (document.layers||document.getElementById&&!document.all){
if (e.which==2||e.which==3){
alert(message);
return false;
}
}
}

if (document.layers){
document.captureEvents(Event. );
document.onmousedown=clickNS4;
}
else if (document.all&&!document.getElementById){
document.onmousedown=clickIE4;
}

document.oncontextmenu=new Function("alert(message);return false")


</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

    function disableselect(e) { 
        return false 
    } 

    function reEnable() { 
        return true 
    } 
    //if IE4+ 
    document.onselectstart = new Function("return false") 

    if (window.sidebar) { 
        document.  = disableselect 
        document.onclick = reEnable 
    } 
</script>




<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        // Convert anchor names the same way Muse does
        function convertAnchorNames(name) {
            return name.replace(/([A-Z])/g, function (a, c) {
                return c.toLowerCase();
            });
        }

        var anchors = $('a:not([href])'),
            ignoreList = " ".split(/\s*,\s*/),
            dir = "vert";

        if( ignoreList && ignoreList.length && !(ignoreList.length == 1 && ignoreList[0] == '') ) {
            // We're ignoring some
            for(var i in ignoreList) {
                ignoreList[i] = convertAnchorNames(ignoreList[i]);
            }
            anchors = anchors.filter(function (i, el) {
                return ignoreList.indexOf(el.id) < 0 ? el : null;
            });
        }

        // Sort
        var sortFn;
        switch (dir){
            case "vert":
                // Sort items by vertical position top to bottom
                sortFn = function (a, b) {
                    return $(a).offset().top - $(b).offset().top;
                };
                break;
            case "horiz":
                // Sort items by horizontal position left to right
                sortFn = function (a, b) {
                    return $(a).offset().left - $(b).offset().left;
                };
                break;
            default:
                // Sort items from top left to bottom right
                sortFn = function (a, b) {
                    if($(a).offset().top == $(b).offset().top)
                        return $(a).offset().left - $(b).offset().left;
                    return $(a).offset().top - $(b).offset().top;
                };
        }
        anchors.sort(sortFn);

        // Use the current window scroll position to figure out what
        // anchors we are currently between, so we can determine
        // next and previous anchors in our list
        function findCurrentAnchor() {
            if(dir == 'horiz') {
                var currAt = $(window).scrollLeft(),
                    compVal = 'left';

            } else {
                var currAt = $(window).scrollTop(),
                    compVal = 'top';
            }

            var pos = 0;
            anchors.each(function (i, el) {
                if( Math.floor($(el).offset()[compVal]) > currAt) {
                    return false;
                }
                pos = i;
            });

            return pos;
        }

        // Trigger Muse anchor navigation to give anchor
        function navigateTo(anchor) {
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = '#' + anchor.id;
            a.className = 'anim_swing';
            // This is the native Muse function for navigating
            // to a hyperlink. THIS IS UNSAFE, but most reliable
            // way to navigate consistently
            Muse.Utils.processHyperlink(a);
            return false;
        }

        // Go to the next anchor
        function nextAnchor() {
            var i = findCurrentAnchor() + 1;
            if(i < anchors.length) {
                return navigateTo(anchors[i]);
            }
        }

        // Go to the previous anchor
        function prevAnchor() {
            var i = findCurrentAnchor() - 1;
            if(i >= 0) {
                return navigateTo(anchors[i]);
            }
        }

        // Handle all keydown events. Currently no focus
        // distinctions are made
        $(document.documentElement).keydown(function (e) {
                var code = e.keyCode;

                if(true) {
                    switch(code){
                        case 38: // up
                        case 37: // left
                            return prevAnchor();
                        case 40: // down
                        case 39: // right
                            return nextAnchor();
                    }
                }
                if(true) {
                    switch(code){
                        case 34: // page down
                            return nextAnchor();
                        case 33: // page up
                            return prevAnchor();
                    }
                }
            });

    })();
</script>



</body></html>
```

Comment: Could you still show us your code? Perhaps someone can still help.

Comment: Thank you @4castle I have added the code as best I can given the limit to characters and the extremely lengthy chunks of code Muse spits out by default. I hope it useful here but I hadn't done so before because it wouldn't allow the full code to be included. I worry I may have added errors that are not relevant to the question :P 

Hope it's of use, and thank you for your comment. :)